# XSLT 1.0 - instead of function

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following code in XSL 2.0. However, due to limitations imposed by the environment I have to revert to XSL version 1.0. Since functions are not allowed in XSL 1.0, how would I go about doing following in 1.0?

```
 <!-- a custom 'contains' implementation -->
 <xsl:function name="my:contains" as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="str" as="xs:string" />
  <xsl:param name="list" as="xs:string+" />
  <xsl:variable name="temp" as="xs:boolean*">
    <xsl:for-each select="$list">
      <xsl:if test="contains($str, .)">
        <xsl:sequence select="xs:boolean('true')" />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:sequence select="if ($temp[1] = xs:boolean('true')) then xs:boolean('true') else xs:boolean('false')" />
 </xsl:function>      

  <xsl:param                      name = "excludedSections"
                                select = "('AboutThis','79','GetMore')"/>


**Being used as** 



    <xsl:if test = "(not(my:contains($sectionId, $excludedSections))
                                              and
                                              (contains(
                                                concat(' ', @IncludedDevices, ' '), 
                                                concat(' ', $targetedDevice, ' ')
                                                ) `enter code here`
                                               or 
                                               not(@IncludedDevices)
                                              ) 
                                              and 
                                              (not(contains(
                                                concat(' ', @ExcludedDevices, ' '), 
                                                concat(' ', $targetedDevice, ' ')
                                                )) 
                                               or 
                                               not(@ExcludedDevices)
                                              ))">
           .......Do something....
    </xsl:if>
```

Thanks,
GP

Comment: You may consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you are looking for a review of given code.

Comment: @StephenReindl This is about "translating" the current code from 2.0 to 1.0 which does **not** belong on Code Review

Comment: @GP_help, if your comment refers to my answer then you can accept it so that your question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can write a named template to implement a callable block of code in XSLT 1.0.
However it seems you simply want to check whether your list contains a string which the first argument contains so assuming you have `exsl:node-set` (define `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"`) I would define the list as a result tree fragment and convert it to a node-set:

```
<xsl:param name="excludedSectionsRtf">
  <item>AboutThis</item>
  <item>79</item>
  <item>GetMore</item>
</xsl:param>

<xsl:variable name="excludedSections" select="exsl:node-set($excludedSectionsRtf)/item"/>
```

and then the contains check becomes `<xsl:if test="not($excludedSections[contains($sectionId, .)])">...</xsl:if>` which basically checks there is no item contained in `$sectionId`.

That assumes your XSLT 2.0 function could be simplified to

```
<xsl:function name="my:contains" as="xs:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="str" as="xs:string" />
  <xsl:param name="list" as="xs:string+" />
  <xsl:sequence select="some $s in $list satisfies contains($str, $s)"/>
</xsl:function>
```